# Amazon elastic-beanstalk: eb init ERROR: TypeError :: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running `eb init` and going through the steps on Mac OSX. When we get to this part:

```
Enter Branch Name
***** Must have at least one commit to create a new branch with CodeCommit *****
(default is "master"):
```

it always exits the process and returns:

```
ERROR: TypeError :: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Comment: What version of the eb tools are you using? Also, what if you specify the branch instead of just pressing `Enter`?

Comment: Could you run the command again and specify the `--debug` flag and post the stack trace you get back from the error?